# Magento2: Create new product type same as bundle

Tags: bundle, magento2

I want to create new product type in magento2 based on bundle product. I should be able to add bundle items for the parent product as we do for bundle product.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, share it here.

Comment: I've followed this tutorial http://magenest.com/creating-new-product-type-and-product-attribute-in-magento-2/ and able to add new product type. However I'm not able to add bundle items tab while adding product.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: I'm able to open it at my end. Don't know what is the issue at your end. May be due to firewall but not sure.

Comment: "cannot find server magenest.com"

Comment: see this [link](http://prntscr.com/d73x9v)